# How do I do a batch insert in jOOQ with raw SQL?

Tags: java, jdbc, jooq

I need to do a batch insert with a dynamically constructed SQL.

Examples in the documentation that I found all use jOOQ-generated table wrapper classes, which I don't have here, and I would prefer not to have to figure out and specify column names (the insert uses all columns in the table's defined order).

How do I do that?

I've tried the following, but it does not work (bind variables all end up as NULL).

```
import org.h2.Driver;
import org.jooq.DSLContext;
import org.jooq.impl.DSL;
import org.junit.Test;

public class BatchBindTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = new Driver().connect("jdbc:h2:./batchBindTest", null);
        DSLContext x = DSL.using(conn);
        x.execute("create table test(id integer not null)");


        // this does not work, value is not bound
        x.batch("insert into test values(?)").bind(1).execute();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a bug in jOOQ 3.4.2: [#3547](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3547)

[`DSLContext.batch(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batch-java.lang.String-) is just convenience for [`DSLContext.batch(Query)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batch-org.jooq.Query-), wrapping the query string in a plain SQL `Query` type. Unfortunately, the number of bind values need to be known in order to apply bind values. So, a workaround for this issue would be to write:

```
x.batch(x.query("insert into test values(?)", new Object[1])).bind(1).execute();
```

That's of course only a workaround before #3547 is fixed.